# Jquery: fadeIn() a div in rows of divs: Visible divs should be pushed to the right.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two rows of divs, in each row there are three divs next to each other like so:

```
[1] [2] [3]

[4] [5] [6]
```

I hide the first three divs:

```
[4] [5] [6]
```

After some time each hidden div should fade in and pushes the visible divs to the right like so:

```
// after some time
[3] [4] [5]

[6]

// after some time
[2] [3] [4]

[5] [6]


// after some time
[1] [2] [3]

[4] [5] [6]
```

When all the heights/widths of the divs are the same, it is easy: https://jsfiddle.net/0j53L9pz/2/

However when my divs have different heights, it gets a little bit messy. https://jsfiddle.net/0j53L9pz/3/

I've looked into clearfix and/or clear:both, but I cannot figure out where to put it. My goal: I want to have two clean rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox is your friend! Simply add a display flex to your container and you're all set.

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0j53L9pz/4/

Comment: Wow, this is amazing, never have heard about flexbox (though it's not surprising since I'm a CSS newbie, hehe). Thank you!